# Limit point and closure of a set

Tags: real-analysis

i need some help here.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x$ be a limit point of the closure of $A$.

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence in closure of $A$ such that $x_{n}\neq x, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_{n}$ converges to $x$.

Define the sequence $(y_{n})$ as the following:

If $x_{n} \in A$, then let $y_{n} = x_{n}$

If $x_{n}$ is not an element of $A$, then let $y_{n} = a$ for some $a \in \epsilon$ neighborhood of $A$ and $a \in A$.

My question is, why is $y_{n} \neq x$? I could see that it is true if $x_{n} \in A$. But not for the other case.

Answer (score 0):

You can choose $\epsilon$ to be $<\lvert x_n-x\rvert$. Precisely, you are actually choosing an $\epsilon_n$, and you can choose it to be, say, $\min\left\{\frac12\lvert x_n-x\rvert,\, 2^{-n}\right\}$. There will certainly be $y_n\in A$ in that $\epsilon_n$-neighbourhood of $x_n$ and, since $\lvert y_n-x_n\rvert<\lvert x-x_n\rvert$, forcibly $y_n\ne x$.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a guess as to what you're asking here. I suspect that the point of the exercise is to show that if $x$ is a limit point of $A$, then there is a sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ in $A$ which converges to $x$. If I am assuming correctly, then the reason we can't necessarily define $y_n = x$ for some/all $n$ is that you don't know whether or not $x \in A$. If $x$ is not in $A$, then setting $y_n = x$ would force the sequence $(y_n)_{n=1}^{\infty}$ outside of $A$, which is at odds with your desired goal of creating a sequence completely contained in $A$.